# Can't npm start in goormIDE

Tags: reactjs, npm

I can start npm in Windows 10 laptop, but I can't start npm in goormIDE (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

I read the debug log 10 times, but I don't know what to do.

```
sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 126

npm ERR! carcommunity@0.1.0 start: `set PORT=80 && react-scripts start`

npm ERR! Exit status 126

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the carcommunity@0.1.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-08-12T11_03_24_134Z-debug.log
```

This is debug.log:

```
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:259:5)

14 verbose pkgid carcommunity@0.1.0

15 verbose cwd /workspace/carCommunity

16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-1111-aws

17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"

18 verbose node v10.16.3

19 verbose npm  v6.11.3

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 126

22 error carcommunity@0.1.0 start: `set PORT=80 && react-scripts start`

22 error Exit status 126

23 error Failed at the carcommunity@0.1.0 start script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you set it up, you would probably need to run npm as sudo. So, try with sudo react-scripts start.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i used  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS! but, sudo npm start was same!

Comment: thank you for the answer again. I found a answer.  created new app and pasted my code! :)